# Edited library .cpp isn't changing/compiling

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I've made some minor changes to a library (just the .cpp, not .h), and the changes aren't taking effect when compiling. Even outlandish errors have no effect.

I've tried in VS2015 (my normal environment), latest Arduino IDE, and the 1.6.5 IDE. I've also manually erased the .o files.

The .cpp doesn't exist anywhere else. There are no errors to the console, and nothing interesting happens in the full compile log.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

.cpp:

```
/*
 * MozziGuts.cpp
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Tim Barrass.
 *
 * This file is part of Mozzi.
 *
 * Mozzi by Tim Barrass is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.
 *
 */

 #if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#ifdef EAC                      
#include <SPI.h>
#endif
...
```

.h:

```
/*
 * MozziGuts.h
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Tim Barrass.
 *
 * This file is part of Mozzi.
 *
 * Mozzi by Tim Barrass is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.
 *
 */

#ifndef MOZZIGUTS_H_
#define MOZZIGUTS_H_

//#define F_CPU 8000000 // testing

#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif
#ifdef EAC                      //  Euro
#include <SPI.h>
#endif
#include "mozzi_analog.h"
...
```

.ino:

```
/*  Plays a fluctuating ambient wash,
    using Mozzi sonification library.

    Demonstrates audio and control rate updates.
    There are 8 oscillators updated at control rate to set
    the volume of 8 audio oscillators.  Updating the volume
    at control rate saves processor time, incrementing the
    Oscils only 128 times per second rather than at the
    audio rate of 16384 Hz.

    Circuit: Audio output on digital pin 9 on a Uno or similar, or
    DAC/A14 on Teensy 3.1, or 
    check the README or http://sensorium.github.com/Mozzi/

    Mozzi help/discussion/announcements:
    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozzi-users

    Tim Barrass 2012, CC by-nc-sa.
*/

//#include <ADC.h>  // Teensy 3.1 uncomment this line and install http://github.com/pedvide/ADC



bool EACtest;
#define EAC
//#ifdef EAC
#include <SPI.h>
//#endif
#include <MozziGuts.h>
...
```

(I added the SPI.h define/includes.)

Comment: Is the .cpp file you are changing listed as part of your Visual Studio project file?

Comment: Are all the #if etc. matched properly?

Comment: Yes, the files were brought into the VS project properly. I switched to just the Arduino IDE in case VS was causing the problem.

Comment: Yes the #Ifs and all others are okay. I just double-checked against the source to be sure.